# React Native keyboard (multiline)

Tags: android, react-native

My question is for the keyboard type that appears when doing a multiline textinput.

```
<TextInput
   keyboardType="default"
   multiline={false}
   editable={true}
   onChangeText={(text) => this.updateSharedObject({note: text})}
   value={this.state.data.note}
   placeholder="Press to type..."
   placeholderTextColor="#c0c0c0"
   underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
   autoCapitalize="sentences"
   style={[styles.textArea, {height: this.state.height}]}
   onContentSizeChange={(e) => 
   this.updateSize(e.nativeEvent.contentSize.height)}
 />
```

When a user tries to type in the field they get this kind of keyboard.

[image]

The problem is I need to make the field a multiline field. When I set it to true the keyboard becomes this.

[image]

Is there anyway to keep the first keyboard layout while still making it multiline? I have been looking everywhere but have not found anything to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<TextInput returnKeyType='done' />
```

Comment: ya this was it i ended up figuring it out. but thanks!